# how should i use transaction when i wanna use two bounded Context DbContext (Entity Framework core)?

Tags: transactions, entity-framework-core, bounded-contexts

I am programming with c# with Entity Framework Core ,
I have many bounded Context and each of them have their special Database, so when i use database of bounded Context 1 in bounded context 2 i must use transaction , 
but how ?
with which flow ?